# How can i draw Arc in center of the screen on canvas in android

Tags: android

`RectF rectf = new RectF(10, 100, 700, 800);
c.drawArc(rectf, 0, 90, true, paint);`

the above code is draw the arc using drawArc() method of canvas but i try to draw arc in a center of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: in `onDraw()` method:

```
int height = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
int width = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
mRectF.set(width - 100, height - 100, width + 100, height + 100);
```

Don't initialize `rectF` in `onDraw`, do it in a separate method like `init()` or something else. Set the co-ordinates in `onDraw()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will draw an arc in the center of your view:

```
int y = c.getHeight();
RectF rectf = new RectF(getLeft(), y - 100, getRight(), y);
c.drawArc(rectf, 0, -180, true, paint);
```

Note: `c` is an instance of Canvas as used in the question.